# Multiple animejs animations at the same time

Tags: animejs

One of the first things I discovered playing with animejs API was that I could play 2 animations at the same time by simply calling the anime function twice.

Fast forward, I'm now trying to make a complex animation using a timeline. Nothing too difficult, just A then B then C .. then Z

Now I found difficult to have something like A then (B&C at the same time) then D.

It should be doable by adding C with relative offset of "-B.duration" but this looks odd... Does it exists a better way to do it?

Thanks